# boost ptr vector correct way to erase one element

Tags: boost, ptr-vector

I have a list called `mesh_list;`

which is a `boost::ptr_vector<mesh> mesh_list;`

now I want to delete one element from it.

inside of mesh object it has 1 pointer which I newed from constructor,they are:

```
texture* tex;
```

now it is a normal pointer, Do I have to delete it before erase the mesh element from list?

what if I change the texture pointer to shared_ptr,what advantage will I get? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boost Pointer Containers *always* own their elements.

This implies they will *always* manage deletion of these elements.

The purpose of the Pointer Containers is so you can have runtime polymorphic elements *without* worrying about the lifetime of the elements.

**BUT**: the pointer contained by the `mesh` object is /just/ a pointer and you need to free it as always.

Either

- follow Rule Of Three
- use `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr<>`
- you could use `shared_ptr<>` but that's almost always overkill - unless you actually want to share ownership.

Here's a demonstration that shows how `scoped_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` can all be used to similar effect, and that `texture*` will, by itself, leak (unless you implement Rule Of Three for the `mesh` class):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d132b47eaaed363)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct texture {
    virtual ~texture() {}
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

struct texA : texture { virtual void foo() const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " "; } };
struct texB : texture { virtual void foo() const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " "; } };

template <typename Pointer> void test() {

    struct mesh {
        Pointer _ptr;

        mesh()    : _ptr(new(texA)) {}
        mesh(int) : _ptr(new(texB)) {}

        void bar() const { _ptr->foo(); }
    };

    boost::ptr_vector<mesh> meshes;
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        if (rand()%2)
            meshes.push_back(new mesh(i));
        else
            meshes.push_back(new mesh());
    }

    for (auto& m : meshes)
        m.bar();
}

#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <memory>

int main() {

    //  non-leaking methods
    test<boost::scoped_ptr<texture> >(); // scoped_ptr_mesh
    test<std::unique_ptr<texture> >();   // std_mesh
    test<std::shared_ptr<texture> >();   // shared_mesh

    // uncommenting the next causes textures to be leaked
    // test<texture*>();                    // leaking_mesh
}
```

Comment: Added a "visual" demonstration of different approaches. You can use your favourite heap checker to verify that none of the smart pointer approaches leak